# Integrating independent Automation job with jenkins pipeline

Tags: asynchronous, jenkins, automation, jobs

In my organization, we are using jenkins pipeline as code (groovy script). Now i want to integrate my independent automation job with that pipeline but the condition is that it should be triggered asynchronously which means after successfully executing of the development code it will triggered my automation job but pipeline should not wait for my job to end

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using Parallel stages with declarative Pipeline as follows:

```
stage('run-parallel-branches') {
    steps {
        parallel(
            executeDevCode: {
                //Perform job for code execution 
            },
            executeAutomation: {
                //Perform automation job
            }
        )
    }
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

Comment: will it slow down the complete process ?.. i mean they want, once dev job will success it will trigger automation job and pipeline should completed just by triggering it.. automation job will strat and executing independently

Comment: The method will start executing the task in parallel. If you need sequential then just use different stages. It all depends on your requirements. And even if it slows, you can at max do it in parallel.